# How does one define what a rule is in the game Hex-Hex?

Tags: hex-hex

In the card game Hex-Hex, there is a specific rule that says that the winner of a game can introduce a new rule in the next game. Long ago, while playing this game, I once performed an example of a Loki's Wager fallacy by saying that, unless one of the other players can formally define what a "rule" is, I do not agree to play by the new rule. However, that does raise the question, is there a definition of what a valid "rule" is in the game Hex-Hex? Or is this one of those things where there is no formal definition of the thing? I am genuinely interested in this, because I am someone who is obsessed with formal and rigorous definitions for everything. But if there is no such definition, then I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What counts as "introducing"? What counts as "next"? What counts as "game"?

Everything in the rules that are already written down relies on some level of implication, some level of un-define-ability, and requiring a perfectly logical definition of this word and no others is unreasonable.

If you can accept any other word commonly used without forcing others to define a *rule* in general, you can accept what is probably meant by the use of the word *rule* in this rule itself, and seek clarification of any rule that is specifically created as a result.

Anything more than that is being obnoxious to others, merely to avoid the consequence of losing the previous game, and you should expect to quickly find yourself with bigger issues than what rules the next game has - like not having a next game to play at all.